# Java - Help Understanding a Method to modify a String based on width of println

Tags: java, string, loops, methods

I am trying to create a method that will take 2 user input integers, undertake various simple mathematical functions and then print the results centred under a `println` describing the applied function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ColumnResize
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Enter 2 numbers"); 

        int number1 = scanner.nextInt();
        int number2 = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println( "| number 1 |"
        +"| number 2 |"
        +"| add |"
        +"| subtract |"
        +"| times |"
        +"| divide |");

        System.out.print(columnResize(number1 +""));
        System.out.print(columnResize(number2 +""));
        System.out.print(columnResize((number1 + number2) +""));
        System.out.print(columnResize((number1 - number2) +""));
        System.out.print(columnResize((number1 * number2) +""));
        System.out.print(columnResize((number1 / number2) +""));


        scanner.close();
    }

    private static String columnResize(String numberIn)
    {

        return ("|" +numberIn +"|");    
    }
}
```

This allows the user to input 2 numbers and display the results of the function in the next line

The next step is to add a loop to the method to add spaces before and after each result so it is centred in the space, but I can't figure out how I would do this

What I am getting is:

Enter 2 numbers
2
2
| number 1 || number 2 || add || subtract || times || divide |
|2||2||4||0||4||1|

What I need is:

Enter 2 numbers
2
2
| number 1 || number 2 || add || subtract || times || divide |
|     2    ||     2    ||  4  ||     0    ||   4   ||    1   |

Really appreciate any help or guidance

Comment: Surely you can figure out the math. Suppose your number has 4 digits. And your cell has a width of 10. How many spaces do you need before the number, and after the number, in order to have it centered? What's the arithmetic formula to get these two numbers of spaces?

Comment: I think this would work for a single number, but I need it to vary when the user puts in 22 or 222 for example which is where I am having problems.

Comment: Hence my two questions. Why don't you answer them?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. It would be 3 before and 3 after, 10-4 /2 for that example

Comment: OK, so in this formula, 10 is the width of a cell. You have to decide which actual width you want, but I guess this is not a problem. 2 is a constant. And 4 is the number of digits of your integer. So, how could you know how many digits an integer has (given that you need to transform it to a string in order to have it printed anyway)?

Comment: I thought about using the length() method for the number of digits. Is what your taking me to is standardising the width of the original println, then taking the number of digits away from that to get the spaces I need? I then use the for loop to add half the spaces 1 side and half to the other up to the length?

Comment: I think you got it. Except of course you need to decide if the additional space should be before or after the number if the remaining is not divisible by 2 (example: place 222 in a cell of 10 digits).

Comment: Also, please put that in a method. Its signature should look like `String centeredNumber(int numberToCenter, int cellWidth)`. For the arguments `1234` and `10`, it should return a string containing 3 spaces, then 1234, then 3 spaces.